# Чтение количества байт из COM в цикле

Tags: delphi, rs232, циклы

```
repeat
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   InCount:=cp1.InputCount;
until ((InCount >= (Cnt+4)) or TimerExpired(ET));

cp1 - com порт. (TComPot (CPort))

ET - EventTimer
```

InputCount - возвращает к-во байт в буфере.

Cnt+4 - к-во ожидаемых байт.

`cp1.InputCount` в цикле не возвращает реальное к-во байт. Цикл заканчивается только по таймеру(ET).

По окончании цикла InputCount  возвращает к-во байт в буфере.

Comment: Application.ProcessMessages; - зло, нужно убрать. А для чтения из порта сделать отдельный поток и внутри `repeat` поставить `sleep`.
А еще лучше открывать порт с флагом `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` и ожидать в `WaitForMultipleObjects` события получения байт или события завершения потока. При получении байт проверяем сколько получили, если мало, ждем дальше.

Покажите, что у Вас делается в `cp1.InputCount`.

Comment: Что еще за стандартный `TComPort`? Какая версия Delphi?
В таком случае лучше все таки оставить `Sleep` вместо `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: Delphi 7. Не "стандартный" TComPort, а стандартный метод для TComPort. Этот компонент более известен как CPort. Что Sleep, что Application.ProcessMessages - результат одинаковый.

Comment: На сколько таймер стоит?
Покажите где у Вас по окончании цикла проверяется количество байт в буфере. Счетчик полученных байт в `cp1` не сбрасывается после проверки?

Comment: Перед циклом -
 NewTimer(ET,i2);
i2 в зависимости от типа соединения. При работе прибор ---> RS232 --->ПК и при прибор ---> RS232 ---> GSM модем ---> CSD ---> GSM модем --->ПК
В первом случае рассчитывается в зависимости от скорости порта (протокол Modbus), во втором подбиралось опытным путем.
После цикла -  
if InCount >= (Cnt+4) then ...
Счетчик сбрасывается только после чтения из буфера порта в заданный буфер.

Comment: После цикла сразу 68 или перед этим делается что-то еще?
Попробуйте увеличить время между опросами. `Sleep(250)`, например.
Время выполнения `ProcessMessages` может сильно отличаться в зависимости от железа. Чему равно `i2` конкретно в Вашем случае?